# Canonical form of a Quadratic form.

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

I've been given the following quadratic form to find the canonical form of:
$$
Q(\bf{z})= z_1z_2 + 2z_2z_3 − 3z_3z_4
$$

through the method of forming perfect squares.

The method I've been taugh/show is to look at terms consisting of a specific variable, say $z_1$ and form the perfect square. We then set the canonical basis as the inside of the square (hopefully that makes sense...)

Until we get the quadratic form to look like:

$$
Q(z)=\alpha_1(\eta^1)^2+\alpha_2(\eta^2)^2+\alpha_3(\eta^3)^2+\alpha_4(\eta^4)^2
$$
where the alphas are the canonical coefficients.

Now I am stuck with the above problem as there is no square term. Typically my approach in these problems has been to start with a term that has a square term, and go from there. In this case, whenever I get to the final $\eta$ to find, I am left with two square terms, say $z_3$ and $z_4$

Is there something im missing?

Comment: You say "the canonical form", but what does it mean? Quadratic forms have a lot of diagonalizations. Are you working over a special field, like the real numbers, and have a special form in mind? (Like, only $1$ and $-1$, with positive coefficients first, or something like that?)

Comment: I don't know if you've encountered the connection between matrices and quadratic forms yet, but that is very helpful here. Finding the canonical basis us equivalent to diagonalizing the matrix. If that is something that is new to you, try letting $\eta_1=a_1z_1+b_1z_2+c_2z_3+d_1z_4$ and so on, and solving for the $a,b,c,d$. Based on a back of the envelope calculation, the squares you need to find will involve all four variables

Comment: No special form or anything, Sorry if this is vague, I am still coming to grips with quadratic forms. Perhaps an example can best illustrate what Im doing/trying to do:
From G. E Shilov, Linear Algebra

$$
G(x) = \zeta_1^2 +6\zeta_1\zeta_2 +5\zeta_3^2 - 4\zeta_1\zeta_4-12\zeta_2\zeta_3+4\zeta_3^2 -4\zeta_2\zeta_4-8\zeta_3\zeta_4-\zeta_4^2
$$


If we look at the $\zeta_1$ terms and complete the square,

$$\zeta_1^2+6\zeta_1\zeta_2 -4\zeta_1\zeta_3 =(\zeta_1+3\zeta_2-2\zeta_3)^2 -9\zeta_3^2-4\zeta_3^2+12\zeta_2\zeta_3$$
Now define:

$$\eta_1=\zeta_1+3\zeta_2-2\zeta_3$$

and repeat

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the connection between quadratic forms and matrices, like Jacobi method of diagonalisation, however I am specificly interested in the method of perfect squares. If you haven't heard of it can be found in G. E Shilov, Linear Algebra

Comment: The method I am using is the same as detailed in: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2415940/put-quadratic-form-into-sum-of-squares

I obviously have no variable initially that has a square term, and I cannot for the life of me find the transformation to create a sqaure term...

Comment: Gantmacher's writeup of Lagrange's method is shown at https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lagrange_method    where the coefficients are taken from half the Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don’t have any squared terms, a common trick is to pick one of the cross terms $z_iz_j$ and make the change of variables $z_i=\frac12(y_1+y_2)$, $z_j=\frac12(y_1-y_2)$. This change of variables comes from a polarization identity for quadratic forms. You then have a difference of squares with which you can continue.

Here, we can try $z_1=\frac12(y_1+y_2)$, $z_2=\frac12(y_1-y_2)$, obtaining $\frac14y_1^2-\frac14y_2^2+y_1z_3-y_2z_3-3z_3z_4$. After completing the squares a couple of times, you’ll once more be left with only a cross term, so apply another change of variables to it. When you’re all done, substitute for the $y_i$. (The factor of $\frac12$ in the change of variables is there to make this final substitution for the original variables “nicer.”)

Answer (score 1):

Without spelling out all the computations; your quadratic form is given by the symmetric matrix
$${\bf z}\begin{pmatrix}
0&\tfrac12&0&\hphantom{-}0\\
\tfrac12&0&1&\hphantom{-}0\\
0&1&0&-\tfrac32\\
0&0&-\tfrac32&\hphantom{-}0
\end{pmatrix}{\bf z}^{\top}=0,$$
and you want to find a linear transformation $T$ such that
$$(T{\bf z})\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1&0&0&0\\
0&\alpha_2&0&0\\
0&0&\alpha_3&0\\
0&0&0&\alpha_4
\end{pmatrix}(T{\bf z})^{\top}=0,$$
so it suffices to diagonalize the symmetric matrix above.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix identity below says your quadratic form can be written as
$$\frac{1}{4} (x_1 + x_2 + 2 x_3)^2 - \frac{1}{4} (-x_1 + x_2 - 2 x_3)^2 - \frac{3}{4} ( x_3 + x_4)^2 +\frac{3}{4} (- x_3 + x_4)^2 $$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 2 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Algorithm discussed at [reference for linear algebra books that teach reverse Hermite method for symmetric matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr)
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
2 & 2 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
2 & 1 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  - 2 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 6 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{6} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 2 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 2 & 1 \\ 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 &  - 2 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 6 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 2 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\ 
0 & 2 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 3 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 0):

Gantmacher's version of Lagrange's method leads to
$$ \left( \frac{1}{2} x_1 +  \frac{1}{2} x_2 + x_3 \right)^2 - \left( -\frac{1}{2} x_1 +  \frac{1}{2} x_2 - x_3 \right)^2  +  \left( \frac{1}{2} x_2 +  \frac{1}{2} x_3   -\frac{3}{2} x_4 \right)^2 -  \left( -\frac{1}{2} x_2 +  \frac{1}{2} x_3   +\frac{3}{2} x_4 \right)^2$$

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]